# How to use 凭 as a preposition

Tags: word-choice

I understand 凭 as a verb to mean rely. But I often read it and the seemingly related 凭着 in familiar contexts but still do not know what function it serves. Seeing example sentences doesn't make it any clearer. 
In what cases is it most used?

Comment: Based on and according to come to mind. Rely might be not the best translation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are close. 凭着 expresses the idea of *based on*, *according to* or *relying on*, and when translating into English, prepositions such as *on* or *by* can often be used to convey this. You should be able to use it in situations where this concept needs to be expressed. As you suspected, its part of speech is best thought of as prepositional. 凭, when used in this sense, is equivalent to 凭着.

Some examples:

- 她在沙漠里走了一个星期, 就凭(着)太阳的方位来认路. (She walked in the desert for a week,
  **using** only the sun's position for directions.)
- 我们的猫凭(着)它的本能, 走了十五公里的路, 回到了我们以前住的房子. (Our cat went back to
  our previous house having walked fiften kilometres **by** instinct. )
- 你是凭(着)什么文凭来应聘这个职位的? (What certifications **make** you **eligible** for this
  job? / You are applying for this job **based on** what certifications?)

Keep in mind that translation is an art and you do not need to stick with the words that I used. Be flexible.

Comment: Well, all of your examples can also be rewritten with "凭借/憑藉".

Comment: I guess so.. or 凭借着.. (Actually just a side note, I noticed that you've been using both scripts. It's actually not necessary. There are plenty of script conversion sites on the Internet if anyone happens not to understand one or the other. Just thought it'd save you some time. It's nice of you to do that though. )

Answer (score 2):

It means "use". Usually the thing that is used has some specially importance, that is, if this thing is not used, people will not complete the task successfully. For example:

"你用什么来拆我的房子?"--"我用推土机."

"你凭什么来拆我的房子?"--"就凭我是政府!"

Comment: Welcome to the site. An upvote to get you started.

Comment: really like the example sentences